# What would I use instead of org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to upgrade my project to hibernate 5.2.10.Final. I'm using the same version of the hibernate-spatial dependency. I get this error:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType, at table: ---, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(---)]

I was wondering what I should change org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType to for supporting this version of hibernate/hibernate-spatial?

Comment: I don't think you need the UserType at all anymore; it's built into the core Hibernate distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. I was trying org.hibernate.spatial.GeolatteGeometryType but it wasn't working. Ill try not using that and see how it goes